# Time Series with Contextual Data

Tags: python, time-series

I want to predict the demand for a product through time series methods like ARIMA. In addition to historical demand data, I have the data of factors affecting the demand, that is, contextual data. How would it be possible to combine the historical data with contextual data in time series?

I would be thankful if it is possible to share some references. Moreover, I am willing to use Python for prediction. Is there any library in Python for this purpose?